# How to draw line with specific pattern in Inkscape?

Tags: inkscape, svg

I do this...

[image]

I would like to do this, using a square pattern instead of a dashed line:
[image]

How can I do it on Inkscape?

Result:[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the [pattern along path](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Paths-LivePathEffects-PatternAlongPath.html) functionality, you can repeat an arbitrary shape along a path.